# Difference between "valuable" and "invaluable"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives

*Invaluable* intuitively seems to imply a higher degree of importance.

Please explain the difference between *valuable* and *invaluable* and in what context you'd use one or the other.

Comment: Could you clarify what you don't understand after reading the dictionary definitions of [valuable](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/valuable) and [invaluable](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/invaluable)?

Comment: @aedia, the dictionary definitions really don't clarify the meaning properly. I think this is a great question! +1

Comment: I liked how this question is being closed even though it got high votes and sparked a lot of interest. Go figure.

Comment: Indeed, the terse dictionary definitions utterly fail to capture the nuances explored admirably by the existing answers to this question. Questions such as this one are exactly what ELU is supposedly for.

Comment: @phenry Actually, I find the dictionary does a fine job on this one. "invaluable: valuable beyond estimation : priceless <providing invaluable assistance>" (Merriam-Webster)

Comment: I published a paper about [the syntax and semantics of _value, price, cost,_ and _worth_](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf) a while ago.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Technically, *invaluable* works like *priceless*. They mean that something is of a value which cannot be expressed in numbers. For example great memories, happiness, health, or whatever else you prefer. They are invaluable, because they cannot be sold or bought. They have no price.

On the other hand, *valuable* means something is of a high value, which can be expressed in numbers. Like a golden ring. It's valuable, because it costs $1000.

Answer (score 3):

[Valuable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/valuable), in American English, is nearly synonymous with [invaluable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/invaluable), and is generally used to mean something like *useful*.

[In COCA, *valuable* appears](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=12280841) much more than *invaluable*, and it is more common in academic writing (where it might be expected as a formal-sounding synonym for *good*, *important*, *worthwhile*, *things we need*), whereas it is less common in speech. (The speech examples in COCA are from news broadcasters so they may not fully represent unscripted speech.)

From most to least frequent use of *valuable*, here are some examples of how it's used. In academic writing, it almost exclusively has the more figurative meaning of *important*; in other places, it sometimes refers to the high monetary value of real goods.

> [Acad] modern collections management systems will provide easy access to **valuable** additional data
> [Acad] foreign-born faculty members make **valuable** contributions to the research mission
> [Mag] There's a vast supply of **valuable** metal in Alaska
> [Mag] such genetic information will provide **valuable** insights into issues
> [News] thieves who steal copper, brass, bronze and other **valuable** industrial metals
> [News] If you are judging who is the most **valuable** player then I think Wondo has a great shot
> [Fic] A **valuable** piece of pink jade of that size and perfection
> [Fic] from a merchant who was buying a small but **valuable** patch of groznium-rich soil
> [Spok] we're running short of a lot of **valuable** resources, and we don't have that much zinc
> [Spok] There's some really **valuable** tips there, so I would encourage people to take a look

[*Invaluable*, in COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=12281203), occurs less than *valuable*, but follows the same pattern of being used more in academic writing, then magazines, news, fiction and finally least in speech. However, I could not find any instances where it clearly refers to real monetary value. Even when a reference to money is made, the meaning is more like *very important*, so that people say coupon books and funds are invaluable. For example:

> [Acad] Finally, the authors acknowledge the **invaluable** contributions to the project
> [Mag] ferns are **invaluable** for a reliable, low-maintenance understory
> [News] These funds were **invaluable** in giving cash-strapped farmers a chance to remain
> [Fic] the gray kitty is Pewter, Market's **invaluable** assistant, though she's often over here
> [Spok] His leadership has also been **invaluable** in helping our country