# Difference between the terms 'famous' & 'infamous'; 'valuable' & 'invaluable'

Tags: meaning, prefixes, semantics

Question in Short:
Why is it that the terms *valuable* and *invaluable* mean almost the same thing while the terms *famous* and *infamous* are almost semantically opposite in meaning?  That is, one is used to describe something/someone well known for their good qualities, while the other is used to describe something/someone well known for their bad qualities?

Question in Detail:
One of the answers to the question titled [Difference between “valuable” and “invaluable” [closed]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44862/difference-between-valuable-and-invaluable) suggest that the term [valuable](http://thesaurus.com/browse/valuable) is almost synonymous with [invaluable](http://thesaurus.com/browse/invaluable), although the preferred answer points out their subtle differences as being *costly* and *priceless*, respectively.  That is, something that can be bought or sold (*valuable*), as opposed to something that cannot be bought or sold (*invaluable*), yet is treasured.

Why is it that the terms [famous](http://thesaurus.com/browse/famous) and [infamous](http://thesaurus.com/browse/infamous) are not semantically synonymous according to these online references?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between "valuable" and "invaluable"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44862/difference-between-valuable-and-invaluable) @Bill - I can't believe you actually used the ELU site search facility before asking. Variants of this one are *always* being asked.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The prefix *in-* means *not,* and meant *not* in Latin. Both *famous* and *infamous* are derived from Latin roots. And you are asking why *famous* and *infamous* have opposite meanings? This isn't unusual: consider *discreet* and *indiscreet*, *noble* and *ignoble*.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I suppose what bothers OP there is that *famous* and *infamous* both imply "well-known", either positively or negatively. The best we can do for an "antonym" is probably *non-famous*, but that's not exactly in common use.

Comment: I understand the Latin meaning of the 'in-' prefix meaning not, and I suppose to a certain degree it is correctly used to describe the difference between the terms 'famous' versus 'infamous'.  I was simply using 'valuable' and 'invaluable' to describe a situation where it is not used in this context.

Comment: I suppose that currently in English, *famous* just means *well-known* and not *well-known for good qualities* (the word *renowned* better fits this definition). However, I expect that when the *in-* was attached to obtain *infamis* in Latin, it had a meaning closer to *renowned*.

Comment: @PeterShor - Thanks for that Peter.  That is probably closer to the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I suggest better than _non-famous_ is _obscure_ or _little-known_.

Comment: @Andrew: That rather depends on the yardstick by which you measure "better". I was constraining myself to "words" formed using the root **famous**, which left me little alternative.

Comment: @PeterShor Why 'suppose'? *Widely known* **is** the primary meaning of *famous*, check the dictionary, no good or bad is implied. It does not say known for what or how. We had to devise ***ill**-fame* to be clearer, The word *fame* became too famous in a positive sense.

Comment: That was supposed to be part of my answer in fact, but the answer already grew too long.

Comment: @Kris Checking the [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/famous): **famous**: 1a:  widely known
1b:  honored for achievement.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes. The first definition is merely 'widely known', with no connotations. See also etymonline: A native word for this was Old English *namcuð*, literally "name-known."

Answer (score 12):

The prefix does its job faithfully **regardless of the ultimate result** of connotation or implication. Some explanation may be in order.

*in-*: prefix denoting 'not'.
∴
*in* + *famous*  → not famous
&
*in* + *valuable*  → not valuable (Patience!)

*fame*: good reputation; *famous*: widely known for something good;
*infamy* bad reputation; *infamous*: widely known for something bad. – Naturally?

*value* (*n*): worth;
*(to) value* (*v*): to estimate the worth of;
*valuable*: that whose worth can be estimated;
*invaluable*: that whose worth can **not** be estimated; too valuable.

It all adds up nicely.

The prefix modifies in a mechanical way here, while the meaning on the other hand, depends on the nature of the word, its original implication, even its etymology and usage. Even *not valuable* can be understood in the right context to mean something that cannot be valued (*not value+able*).

Comment: Can you apply this logic to 'flammable' and 'inflammable'? Use of the latter is discouraged by safety experts (sorry, no cite) because it can be mistaken for 'not flammable'.

Comment: @JimMack That's a **different** *in-*, the preposition.

Comment: @JimMack The prefix *in* in *inflammable* is not the one we use for deriving an antonym. The *in* there implies the **inherent** nature of a material to burn, i.e., without need for an external source of fire such as a spark. Volatile liquids tend to burn all by themselves without external influence.

Comment: *cf. **inborn***: from ***in*** "within" + *boren*  "brought forth" (etymonline)