# If "in-" forms antonyms, why is "invaluable" not the opposite of "valuable"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, prefixes, etymological-fallacy

I'm not a native speaker. Most of the time when I hear a word that starts with "in-" I think of an opposite, a negation:

- visible – **in**visible
- valid – **in**valid
- dependent – **in**dependent

But I get puzzled by ***invaluable***. This is actually like superlative, right? You have some skill that is valuable and then you have the top skill, the most precious one – the invaluable one.

Am I understanding the words *valuable* and *invaluable* in the wrong way, or is "in-" in this case something different?

Comment: [This earlier question about invaluable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44862/difference-between-valuable-and-invaluable) was closed but the answers cover the same topic.

Comment: Thank you, Stuart for additional reading :)

Comment: Flammable - Inflammable is another confusing one.

Comment: @Grollo Safety signs typically avoid the word *inflammable* to prevent the confusion.  In addition there may be a slight difference in that you can set fire to something flammable with a source of ignition while something inflammable can burst into flames on its own.

Comment: @Grollo [_Why are not "infamous" and "inflammable" the opposite of "famous" and "flammable"?_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/why-are-not-infamous-and-inflammable-the-opposite-of-famous-and-flammable) explains clearly that in the case of _inflammable_ **in-** is not the negative prefix, but rather the preposition _**in**_. Sorted!

Comment: @Henry It doesn't seem that it has been that long ago that placards on hazmat trucks actually used to say INFLAMMABLE. But perhaps it has been a few decades...

Comment: The prefix "in" can take on several different meanings.  It's English!

Comment: It is exactly the same as why "priceless" does not mean "free"

Comment: @Grollo Strunk & White (4th edition) explains the confusion and concludes: Unless you are operating such a truck and hence are concerned with the safety of children & illiterates, use _inflammable_.

Comment: As you can tell from the comments, native speakers are also fascinated by these cases where "in-" seems not to work as the negating prefix we expect.

Comment: Consider also *incorporate*.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

***Valuable*** and ***invaluable*** are not antonyms, but the prefix ***in-*** still means *not*. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/invaluable-not-valuable-usage) explains:

> *Valuable* and *invaluable* do mean similar things, but the *in-* in invaluable isn't playing any tricks. It simply means "not." We think of ***valuable*** as meaning *"having a great deal of value,"* as in *"valuable jewelry"* or *"learned a valuable lesson."*
>
> ***Invaluable***, on the other hand, means ***"valuable beyond estimation."*** Much like ***priceless***, it describes something that is of such a great value that it cannot fairly be quantified.

To understand how ***invaluable*** was formed, [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=invaluable&utm_source=extension_submit) comes handy:

> 1570s, "above value, too valuable for exact estimate," from ***in-** "not"* + ***value*** (v.) "estimate the worth of" + ***-able***. It also has been used in a sense "without value, worthless" (1630s, from in- + valuable).

Although it has been used as the antonym of *valuable* in the past, now that meaning has not survived.

M-W says:

> While the verb *value* often means "*to prize or esteem*" (as in "I value our friendship"), it can also mean "***to estimate or assign the monetary worth of***" or "***appraise***." If something is of such a nature that its importance cannot be stated in monetary terms, that obviously makes it ***unable to be valued***, or ***invaluable***.

Comment: how do we explain "inflammable"? I think I got it: "able to be inflamed"

Comment: @user253751 Correct. Read [_Why are not "infamous" and "inflammable" the opposite of "famous" and "flammable"?_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1578/why-are-not-infamous-and-inflammable-the-opposite-of-famous-and-flammable), might clear it up for you.

Comment: It seems to be that English language doesn't follow very strict rules. Rather, the rules seem to be built to cater for what exists as English language.

Comment: @pakieng Yes! The spoken language came first, then the written language, then the guys who made up the rules.

Comment: One can trace this back to the Latin prefix "in" meaning "into" which can be compared with the Latin prefix "in" meaning "not" (actually from Greek "an."(

Comment: @pakieng It may be more useful to think of English having _patterns_ rather than _rules_. English speakers “simply” try to match what they’re saying to patterns they’ve heard before—but because English borrows so heavily from other languages (and other reasons), there are a lot of patterns and it’s sometimes impossible for things to fit all of them, so English speakers just do their best and whatever “catches on” becomes a new pattern. This is fairly intuitive for native speakers, because they think in these patterns too. It is miserable for non-native learners, unfortunately.

Comment: @SimonCrase Well, in this case English wasn't necessarily at fault.  *Inflammable* means flammable/can combust in French.  French doesn't have the word *flammable* for some reason (nothing seems inherently "wrong" with it, it just doesn't exist).  To denote flameproof, you have "ininflammable" - yes, double ins/ not not.  So at least for this word, blame whatever language originally sourced the mess (French?  Latin?).

Comment: Consider that **price** and **worth** are near-synonyms, but **priceless** and **worthless** are exact opposites.  English is weird sometimes.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Correction: Inflammable means able to be inflamed. According to Cassell's New Latin Dictionary, inflammare  means to kindle or to set fire to.

Comment: @KRyan true that. I am not a native English speaker and I can say very confidently that it was much easier to learn it reading books and watching TV than learning grammar at school.

Answer (score 0):

Invaluable - not valuable. If you brought something that was a fake or worth $0, would it not be invaluable? Like a fake coin would be invaluable.

Comment: Invaluable vs Unvaluable - maybe the difference is there and why you are getting confused.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).